# How to stop other threads stealing focus when debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a server process running in Eclipse 3.4.1.  There are 20 threads or so, waking up at various interval after sleeping.

I set a breakpoint in one method on one thread, and Eclipse stops there properly.  The thread is expanded with a stack trace in the Debug view, and I can use the various buttons to step through.  This is all what I expect.

My problem is that it seems like when another running thread wakes up while I am stepping through, it steals the focus in the Debug view.  My suspended thread is not selected or expanded anymore (it has a + next to it) and all the buttons are disabled.  I have to click back on the suspended thread to continue debugging.

Has anyone seen this before and know any workarounds or settings I could change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above does not help you can always disable all your breakpoints once you are debugging where you want to be.

In the **Breakpoints** view: Ctrl-A, Right click -> Disable

Answer (score 12):

You could suspend the entire Java VM not only the executing thread to get rid of the focus problems.

Select a breakpoint in the breakpoints view and choose "Suspend VM" instead of "Suspend Thread". Under Preferences->Java->Debug you can make "Suspend VM" the default option.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem when debugging Play!Framework 2 applications. What seems to have finally solved it is to uncheck Java -> Monitors in the debug perspective/thread view panel context menu.

Comment: Seems the positive effect didn't last, I'm back with the suspended thread losing focus :-(

Comment: Same here, lasts for a little while (longer) until something kicks it out again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the option to stop all threads at the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work (haven't got an Eclipse install to hand to confirm), but there's a debug option that you could try.

Under **Run/Debug** in the Preferences, there's an option called (something like) **Activate debug view when a breakpoint is hit**. If you uncheck that option Eclipse won't jump the focus to the debug view. It might also stop individual threads stealing the focus.