# Eclipse debugger - jump to or show only suspended thread

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a Java application with a lot of threads. While debugging, and when execution in one thread was stopped by a break point, it's pretty annoying to scroll between all the threads to find the suspended thread. Is there a way (a button, shortcut key, whatever) to jump to the suspended thread, or better - to hide all not suspended threads?

Comment: Maybe same goal as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173068/how-to-stop-other-threads-stealing-focus-when-debugging-in-eclipse , but this is clearer.

Answer (score 36):

I agree it is very annoying, and the answer very disappointing.
But I think I found kind of a way:

- select the Debug view
- type `Ctrl-F` to open the Find window for that view
- type *Suspen
- select the thread you want

Not ideal, but does the job for me.

Comment: I still see this bug in Eclipse Mars... very annoying indeed.

Comment: @duduamar It's still there in Eclipse Mars. I wouldn't call it a bug though, more of a missing feature. Sometimes there are thousands of threads that hog up the list. I wish there was a filter or something else. Maybe a plugin could achieve this?

Comment: Best workaround I've found so far.  But agree - far from ideal - especially when doing remote debug; population of the Find window can take a while.

Answer (score 7):

Using "Eclipse IDE" and in the Debug window there's a down arrow dropdown in the top right of that window/section.

- Click the vertical ellipsis (or the down arrow if using an Eclipse release earlier than 2019-12)
- Click Java
- "Show Running Threads" was defaulted to clicked for me
- Click "Show Running Threads"

Go back into this dropdown and now it's unchecked, doesn't seem to work 100% but definitely trims down on the showing threads