# Eclipse Debugger - how to display suspended threads only

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, debugging, breakpoints

When debugging a J2EE application, in Eclipse, I do see hundreds of Threads.
However, I am interested in a single thread, in which my breakpoint hit.
Going up and forth to find it everytime is a pain.

How do I filter out the unsuspended threads?

Comment: This question duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588196/eclipse-debugger-jump-to-or-show-only-suspended-thread and is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173068/how-to-stop-other-threads-stealing-focus-when-debugging-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is not an easy way to do this. One workaround would be like this:

1. Get a focus on the Debug view
2. Ctrl + F (in order to get the find dialog)
3. Enter something like *Suspended
4. Click OK

Comment: Cool ! But this does not persist in the second breakpoint hit. Do I have to type Ctrl+F each time ?

Comment: @math_law I fear you would have to type Ctrl+F each time. This workaround is the option I am using, I hope the Debug View will be enhanced in the near future, it is a real shame not to have such an easy filtering capability.

Comment: Any updates on a solution that persists (like adding filters)?