# Eclipse - Annoying thread-switching while debugging a thread's execution

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am seeing a very annoying problem with my eclipse. While debugging the execution of a particular thread, when I press `F6` (Step next), the control moves on to some other random thread.

[image]

In the above screenshot, I am debugging `[Thread-691]`, when I step next, *sometimes* eclipse moves away from the selected thread!

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop other threads stealing focus when debugging in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173068/how-to-stop-other-threads-stealing-focus-when-debugging-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when debugging concurrent threads running the same code.  I set a breakpoint in the code and the debugger switches to another thread if that thread happens to hit the same breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry.  Forgot to add that part.  Once you've stopped on a breakpoint, select that breakpoint and select "Breakpoint Properties" from the context menu.  On the filter tab there is a list of threads that you can restrict the breakpoint to.  You'll have to set that filter on any other breakpoint you also want to stop on in the thread.